# Install SSH key in an account that has no "usable" shell

Tags: ssh, ssh-keys

A remote SSH server has a guest account with a known, non-blank password, that when logged in directly executes a text-based terminal game (not sure if via `command`, `shell`, or another method). The connection closes whenever the game exits, so there is no "usable" shell to run commands.

I want to connect to this server using a password-less key, and I've already checked that the SSH server *does* allow keypair authentication. The problem is: how to *add*/*copy* a pubkey to the remote `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file?

I've tried both `ssh-copy-id` and `scp`, and both fail with:

```
me@home ~ $ ssh-copy-id -i ~/.ssh/id_ed25519.game.pub guest@game.example.com
guest@game.example.com's password: 
Error opening terminal: unknown.
me@home ~ $
```

So, given this scenario and that login/password authentication works fine, is there any way to establish a connection without a password?

Answer (score 1):

If the ssh config of the server allows it, you can specify a different command/shell as an argument to the ssh command.

eg:

```
ssh guest@game.example.com /bin/bash
```

However, given that you can't use `ssh-copy-id` nor `scp`, I expect that that sshd config will `ForceCommand` to ignore any command/subsystem request from the client and force the `game` to be run instead. If that's the case, you're out of luck. You will have to find another way to add your key (basically ask the server admin)